# javascript hot and cold game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an app that compares a randomly generated number to a number input by the user. From there the app guides the user via "hotter" and "colder" prompts. I'm close, but right now my issue is that the prompts disappear after being displayed for about 1 second. I want the "hotter" or "colder" prompt to stay visible until the user inputs another number.

Here is a link to the app: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91499081/HotOrCold/HotOrCold.html?guess=&submit=Submit

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
console.log("The secret number is: " + answer);
var numberOfGuesses = 0;
var guesses = [];
var distance = null;
var previousDistance = null;

function getGuess() {
    $("#submit").click(game);
    $("#guess").keydown(function (enter) {
        if (enter.keyCode == 13) {
            game();
        }
    });
}

getGuess();

function game() {
    var guess = parseInt($('#guess').val());
    if (guess !== null && $.isNumeric(guess) && (1 < guess < 101)) {
        $('#guess').val('');
        numberOfGuesses += 1;
        guesses.push(guess);
        distance = Math.abs(answer - guess);
        previousDistance = Math.abs(answer - guesses[guesses.length - 2]);
        if (guess === answer) {
            $('#hint').html('Congrats! You got it in ' + numberOfGuesses + ' attempts! The secret number was ' + answer);
        } else {
            console.log(guess, answer, previousDistance, distance);
            if (isNaN(previousDistance)) {
                if (guess > answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('Guess lower! Last guess: ' + guess);
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('Guess higher! Last guess: ' + guess);
                }

            } else if (distance > previousDistance) {
                if (guess > answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re getting colder, guess lower! Last guess: ' + guess);
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re getting colder, guess higher! Last guess: ' + guess);
                }
            } else if (distance < previousDistance) {
                if (guess > answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re getting hotter, guess lower! Last guess: ' + guess);
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re getting hotter, guess higher! Last guess: ' + guess);
                }
            } else if (distance === previousDistance) {
                if (guess > answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re on fire, guess lower! Last guess: ' + guess);
                } else if (guess < answer) {
                    $('#hint').html('You\'re on fire, guess higher! Last guess: ' + guess);
                }
            } else {
                $('#hint').html('ERROR: Your guess must be a number between 1 and 100').css({
                    color: 'red'
                });
            }
        }
    }
    $('#newgame').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        console.log(answer);
        numberOfGuesses = 0;
        guesses = [];
        distance = null;
        previousDistance = null;
        $('#hint').html('');
        $('#guess').val('');
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Add a `onsubmit="return false"` to your form. Or change the submit button to have `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: I was going to say try to isolate the problem further to get a sensible answer but I guess putvande proved me wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is in your HTML. You have a submit button that is part of a form. When you click submit, it is looking for a form action which isn't specified so it is reloading the page.

Change your `<form>` tag to keep you on the same page by changing it from this:

```
<form id="myform">
```

to this:

```
<form id="myform" action="#">
```

Or even better, make it so the JS function returns `false` so that the submit won't go through.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `<input type="submit" />` button. When it's clicked, your form will attempt to fire off whatever is in the `action` attribute, which is reloading your page.

You have many options.

I would just use `<input type="button" />` or `<a href="#">Submit</a>`. Then fire off the event when the `button` or `link` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your form performs its normal behaviour: post its data to the server. You need to disabled that action. You can either change your 'submit' button to be a normal button so it won't behave as submit:

`<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="button"/>`

Or add a onsubmit to your form:

`<form id="myform" onsubmit="return false">`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting regularly. Since you do not have any action attribute in your form, it will submit your form to the current page. What you want, is to handle the submit with javascript:

```
<form id="myform">
```

and in your javascript:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', game);
function game(event) {
    // your code goes here
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

in this way also enter will trigger a post which is handled by javascript, instead of only clicking a submit button.